# how to press buttons of keyboard without sending keys in searchbox? means to just do Keys.PAGE_DOWN instead of searchbox.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

python selenium
**how to press buttons of keyboard without sending keys in searchbox?
means i want to just do Keys.PAGE_DOWN instead of searchbox.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)**
i want to scroll through instagram feed by send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
but to do this i have to send keys in searchbox but by that a popup box appears when we click on searchbox
so how can we use page down button on keyboard without typing in searchbox?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions 
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/')
time.sleep(2)
# PUT YOUR USERNAME
username = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="loginForm"]/div/div[1]/div/label/input')
username.send_keys('')
time.sleep(2)
#PUT YOUR PASSWORD
password = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="loginForm"]/div/div[2]/div/label/input')
password.send_keys('')
time.sleep(2)
log = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="loginForm"]/div/div[3]/button/div')
log.click()
time.sleep(4)
save_info = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/div/div/div/button')
save_info.click()
time.sleep(2)
notification = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div/div[3]/button[2]')
notification.click()
time.sleep(3)
searchbox = driver.find_element_by_class_name("x3qfX")
for i in range(0,5):
    searchbox.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
    time.sleep(1)
```

[see this screenshot there is RECENTS popup box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNbMp.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to send `Keys.PAGE_DOWN` to the search box.
Do this instead:

```
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
```

This should scroll page down as if you do that manually by pressing the Page Down key on the keyboard.

Comment: @PranavPatil Great! If so please accept my answer

Comment: actually i am new to stack overflow can you guide how to accept solution?

Comment: It's a kind of saying "Thanks" to person who helped. BTW it will give you 2 points